# FOSUserBundle - add login extra field

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7

I have a registration form with extra field. Below is my code:

**service.yml**

```
services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: AppBundle\Form\FOSUserBundle\Registration\RegistrationType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

**My extended registration form:**

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('company', new CompanyForm(), [
            'label' => 'form.company.header', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

**Comapny form:**

```
class CompanyForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text',  [
            'label' => 'form.company', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'
        ]);
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Company',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_form_company';
    }
}
```

**User entity:**

```
class User extends BaseUser
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    use Bleamable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $company;
```

**Comapny entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"identifier"})
 * 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
 */
class Company
{
    use Timestampable;
//    use Bleamable;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $identifier;
```

So basicly while registration user must provide company name
[image]

I want to add that company name to login form and check if it is valid.
If `username`, `password` and `company name` is OK user should be logged in. I know how to override `fos_user_registration` but I can't find information about login form... Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `LoginFormType` or equivalent. You must override the **login template** (easy) and add custom logic for taking the new field value into account, namely, create a custom **User Provider** (less easy) : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html.

You can look at FOSUserBundle's one to get an idea :
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Security/UserProvider.php

#### For the template

As per the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html), the easiest solution is to :

> *Define a new template of the same name in the `app/Resources` directory*

For the login, the template is called `login.html.twig` and is in a folder called **Security**.

You can copy the original [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig).

After having copied it in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security`, just add the lines you need, like :

```
<label for="company">{{ 'your.company'|trans }}</label>
<input type="text" id="company" name="company" value="{{ company }}" required="required" />
```

If you want to enforce validation on the `company` field, you should override validation too : see https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new LogIn form in the child bundle that you have created for FOSUserBundle. This form declare it as a child of the LoginForm of the FOSUserBundle and then add a new field for the Company. Then override the Security/loginAction and render the new form you just created and not the default one of the FOSUserBundle.